# Net work required to bring an object with kinetic energy to stop?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy, work

Am I right in assuming that if an object, let’s say a car, is travelling with kinetic energy of $x$, then the net work required to stop the object would be $ x $ Joules, but in the opposite direction?

Comment: A force in the opposite direction does a negative work on the object that brings the kinetic energy to zero.

Comment: To be clear, what do you (OP) mean by "direction"? Are you thinking of the distinction of work done *on* or *by* an object? Or are you thinking of an actual direction that is a property of a *vector* and not a *scalar*?

Answer (score 5):

Energy does not have a direction. It is a real number, but it is signed. So the work that must be done on the car will be $W=-x$ but that does not imply a directionality for the work.

Comment: Work is always positive. The minus just helps you keep track of which system is doing the work.

Comment: @TheoreticalMinimum No, the definition of work allows for negative values. In fact, if work is always positive, all potential energies would be negative. Negative work is done by a force when that force has a component opposite the direction of motion in the reference frame being used.

Comment: @BillN You make the silly assumption I would not switch my frame of reference from the environment to the system as I please. If you want to stay in one you need the sign.

Comment: By the way, just by flipping the sign of the potentials you don't make all work positive, you just make the processes with negative work positive and the ones with positive work negative.

Comment: @TheoreticalMinimum that is a terrible idea. Just as you are free to switch perspective, I am free to not.

Comment: @Dale Well, never said its useful, but its fun thinking about it.

Comment: @TheoreticalMinimum An elementary application of Newton’s second law proves the work-energy theorem, which equates the net work done on an object to the change in its kinetic energy. If work was always positive, kinetic energy could never decrease.

Comment: @TheoreticalMinimum Work is not always positive. Unless line integrals can't be negative?

Comment: @J. Murray I think we all agree on this, but you don't get my point. If the work on the object is negative (system loses kinetic energy), you can instead talk about positive work being done on the environment, e.g. compression of the string stopping the object. You don't NEED the minus sign. It is just convenient to have it, it allows you to always stay in the frame of the object and not put up with writing "Work done by spring", "Work done by object" and so on.

Comment: @BioPhysicist Clearly work can be negative when just blindly applying the integral definition, I never implied it couldn't be. I'm only saying that you can always give it in positive terms by appropriately chosing the frame of reference. For an engineer e.g. a combustion engine is doing work ($\Delta$W>0) on the environment, for us physicist the engine is losing work with each cycle ($\Delta$W<0). I'm surprised you are all getting so confused about this.

Comment: @TheoreticalMinimum “you can always give it in positive terms by appropriately chosing the frame of reference” is simply not true. Consider a block sliding across a rough floor. From the floor’s frame the work on the floor is 0 and the work on the block is negative. From the block’s frame the work on the block is 0 and the work on the floor is negative. From the frame of a third object traveling in the same direction but at a slower speed than the block the work on both the block and the floor is negative. Your idea is simply not always correct, and it is rather useless where it is valid

Comment: @TheoreticalMinimum comments are for improving the question or answer. They are not for pushing “useless but fun” ideas. Frankly, your idea is wrong. Work is not always positive. By your same “logic” you could say that work is always negative. But in any case your idea ignores cases where the displacements are in opposite directions, or where the force is from a field so there is no other perspective to take. Anyway, this stuff doesn’t belong in comments. It either belongs as its own answer or in a chat. Please respect the rules and place content in the correct location, which is not here.

Comment: @TheoreticalMinimum You're right, you didn't imply it. You explicitly stated "*Work is always positive*". The issue isn't confusion, but rather that this is a false statement. Plus you're not even describing a change of reference frame in your engine example, you're just describing Newton's third law. I don't think anyone has an issue with the conditions you had layed out, but saying work is always positive, then changing your conditions and saying you didn't say that, and then getting confused as to why people are challenging you is pretty dishonest.

Comment: I never changed anything @BioPhysicist. If you chose to ignore the second sentence of my first comment, this is not my problem. You can always only work with positive signed work as I outlined above. By frame of reference in this context one is not talking about a coordinate system, but about the physical system you consider as internal. You can consider the engine as the internal system or flip it around and see the surroundings as internal system. This always gives you a sign change. Works every time two systems do some work on each other. Your accusations are just ridiculous.

Comment: @TheoreticalMinimum first this is not the place for this discussion. This should be an answer or a chat. Second, what you are describing is not a change of reference frame, it is a change of system. Third, even using change of system it is still not a correct claim. It fails for example in the case of a block sliding across a rough floor and also for a two-body gravitational interaction where the bodies are moving apart. Fourth, the laws of physics work for any system designation, so systems with negative work are valid. Fifth, your idea provides no benefit even where it is not wrong

Answer (score 0):

Imagine if the car hit a box and instantly transferred all the energy it had to that box. The car would stop, the box would keep going. The kinetic energy the car had is the same as the work it would do on the box hit by it if that object did not resist:

$x=\frac{1}{2} mv^2$

As Dale pointed out, work is a scalar quantity and does not have a direction, but what I suspect you mean is this: "if the box applied just enough force in the opposite direction to keep from moving, so that the car and box were stopped, how much would that work would that force do?"

Well it would indeed be the same as the kinetic energy, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is correct.

Work = Force x Distance

Air and Axle friction would eventually stop it, brakes or going uphill really help.  This is why "run away truck" exits on mountain roads are ramps to a higher elevation, using
mg(h2-h1) = 1/2mv$^2$ to bring the truck to a halt.

Soft sandy soil is often used to increase drag and help slow the truck as Drag Force x Distance = Work.

The work against the kinetic energy of the truck can be signed "- Work".  Since the units of kinetic energy are the same as the units of Force x Distance, we can say, at a halt:

Kinetic Energy - (Sum of all Braking Work) = 0

The *rate* of Work/Second is referred to as Power.